# Read data from google docs spreadsheets

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

In my app I have to show the details of a google docs spreadsheet.

In this spreadsheet I have 2 sheets. Each sheet details I have to show in 2 different activities.

Can anyone help me out to implement this functionality. What all things are required for this? I found one jar named jxl.jar. Should I use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For:

> programmatically access and manipulate user data stored with Google
>   Documents

there is the [Google Documents List API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/documents/).

If you want to create/edit spreadsheets, you'll need to use the [Google Spreadsheets API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/spreadsheets/).

Both those APIs are part of the gData-API. The Java-client library s (`.jar`-files [which can be used with your Android Project](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list)) can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/).

Comment: The gData-API page says that if you are looking for an Android-compatible API you should instead use the Google API Java Client: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/
Does that sound right?

Comment: Good info, although recently the Google Documents List API is now deprecated, and Google suggests you use the Google Drive API for any future development: https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: Version 3 of the Google Documents List API has been officially deprecated as of September 14, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but we encourage you to move to the Google Drive API.