# Selenium Framework using Google sheets

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-sheets

I am planning to implement hybrid frame work for selenium webdriver project, can we use **google sheets** as data provider(data-driven/keyword)?

If yes Kindly explain how?

1.read data from google sheet for selenium framework.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly are you asking, and this question is probably too broad for this site. Please do your research and come back with a more specific question when you have it.

Comment: Thaks for your reply,

Comment: Question:  like Excel sheet can we use google sheet for selenium framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried but I have found article which can satisfy your requirements

https://dzone.com/articles/reading-data-google

Other references:-

[Read data from Google Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860225/read-data-from-google-spreadsheets)

[Read data from google docs spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566836/read-data-from-google-docs-spreadsheets)

Hope it will help you :)